# How to get common prime factors of a list

Tags: python, primes, factorization

I am trying to calculate prime factors common to all the non-primes. I have computed non-prime integers from the set integers by user input. I can compute prime factors of all the integers present in NotPrime list. My code is as follows:

```
for n in NotPrime:
i=1
while(i<=n):
    k=0
    if(n%i==0):
        j=1
        while(j<=i):
            if(i%j==0):
                k=k+1
            j=j+1
        if(k==2):
            print(i)
    i=i+1
```

where integers in `NotPrime`  are [10,20,30,60]. Code does compute prime factors of each integer in the list. but i want to display common prime factors of the list. How to do it?

Comment: You calculate the factors for each number, then you store them inside a set and combine all sets with & to get which factors are common

Comment: IndentationError for the code above - also not an [mre] - you do not show how you call it with a list or how you store the results or where do you find the common primes

Answer (score 3):

You could compute the gcd with `functools.reduce(math.gcd, [10,20,30,60])`, which is 10. And then use your code on that.

```
import functools, math

NotPrime = [10,20,30,60]

n = functools.reduce(math.gcd, NotPrime)
i=1
while(i<=n):
    k=0
    if(n%i==0):
        j=1
        while(j<=i):
            if(i%j==0):
                k=k+1
            j=j+1
        if(k==2):
            print(i)
    i=i+1
```

Output:

```
2
5
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to keep a dictionary of prime numbers and its occurrences as variable-value pair,
At the end prime numbers with occurrences same as length of input non-primes, are the common factors.

Please refer below code.

```py
NotPrime=[10,20,30,60]
cf={}
for n in NotPrime:
    i=1
    while(i<=n):
        k=0
        if(n%i==0):
            j=1
            while(j<=i):
                if(i%j==0):
                    k=k+1
                j=j+1
            if(k==2):
                if i in cf:
                    cf[i]+=1
                else:
                    cf[i]=1
        i=i+1
print("Common factors")

for a in cf:
    if (cf[a])==len(NotPrime):
        print(a)
```

**Output**

```
Common factors
2
5
```

Comment: you might want to explain that you store the primes as keys in cf and count the occurences of them as value and print out all that have the same amount as numbers provided. Code only answers are frowned upon.